# Schedule a message using alarm manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm working on an Android application which schedules messages to be sent. I'm making use of alarm manager. My main part of the code is as follows:

```
mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = 
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyNotificationService.class);

        mMessage = mEditTextMessage.getText().toString();
        mNumber = mEditTextNumber.getText().toString();
        c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinutes);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putCharSequence("number", mNumber);
        bundle.putCharSequence("message", mMessage);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), 
            pendingIntent);
    }
});
```

How should I implement MyNotificationService class so that it sends the message at the set time? Should that class be a Service or a Broadcast receiver?

Comment: it depends upon u what u want to use, both will use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will allow you to call a broadcast receiver after every 5 seconds.You can use set() ot setTimeZone() method to set at a particular time.

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("abc", Boolean.FALSE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
//After after 5 seconds
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5 , pi);
```

AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver class is a broadcaster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Broadcast receiver for receiving messages from the intent. 
You can create a receiver class where you can have your messages.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MyReceiver.ACTION_REFRESH_ALARM);
pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,0,pendingIntent);

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

   public static final String ACTION_REFRESH_ALARM ="com.paad.network.ACTION_REFRESH_ALARM";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

             //Extract Messages
}}
```